# each or find_each? Or need smart_each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have such code:

```
User.any_scope.each do |user|
  user.do_anything
end
```

if i have big count of users:

```
User.any_scope.find_each do |user|
  user.do_anything
end
```

if users count < 100:

it is not good idea for perfomance to use find_each

What about such code:

```
def smart_each_for(user)
  MAX_COUNT = 100
  user.count > MAX_COUNT ? 'find_each' : 'each'  # 100 - 
end

smart_each = smart_each_for(User.any_scope)

User.any_scope.send :smart_each do |user|
  user.do_anything
end
```

It is good idea for perfomance?
What about MAX_COUNT ? What value should this variable have?

Answer (score 3):

See the docs of [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) method:

> NOTE: It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to
>   ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering
>   work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key
>   is orderable (e.g. an integer or string).
>
> NOTE: You can't set the limit either, that's used to control the batch
>   sizes.
>
> NOTE: By its nature, batch processing is subject to race conditions if
>   other processes are modifying the database.
>
> Note: This method is only intended to use for batch processing of
>   large amounts of records that wouldn’t fit in memory all at once. If
>   you just need to loop over less than 1000 records, it’s probably
>   better just to use the regular find methods.

So no, it is not a good idea to use it in the examples you provided.

Comment: so it is pretty always to use find_each for scopes? Count on scopes always is unknown

Comment: `find_each` is good for processing large amounts of records in rake tasks or background jobs. In your regular app you would rarely need it.